# Expanding Array size in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to use an array in Excel that will return all the values(Tool #s) that match an entered size(Max OD).  I am using the following formula and it works, but I cant expand that array to cover all the required cells.  I can only get it to cover around 100 cells or so.  If I change 100 to even 250 in the formula, the cell just outputs nothing.  I need the array to go from Cell B1 to C1900.  Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($B$1:$C$100,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$100=$R$1,ROW($C$1:$C$100)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($B$1:$C$100,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$100=$R$1,ROW($C$1:$C$100)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Note: I have that formula pasted down and changed the formula to account for the row changes.  So it will be

> ROW(2:2), ROW(3:3)

, etc.  Also the user is to input the size to lookup in cell R1.  Array formulas are located in Cells R4-8.  This is a snipit from a worksheet that contains sensitive data so thats why the formatting isnt the most professional.

Heres a link to the file:
[DROPBOX FILE LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tmnbuguy2ht5pf/DATA.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: You have an absolute reference to the 100th row (everywhere you see `$100`), I assume you have already tried replacing that with `$1900`?

Comment: Yes.  I tried entering 1900 and worked my way down, but when I get much higher than 100,  it outputs nothing.

Comment: There errors inside the table... some #REF... try to change that first...

Comment: That is incomplete Data that hasnt been used since probably the 1960s-1970s.  The data has been pulled from other excel files and thrown into an all inclusive table.  The sheets themselves actually say REF on them as they only have info on Min OD and not a Max OD.  But thats here nor there. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the errors in the rows 224, 233, 237, 249, 1383 it worked with 2000

Comment: Thank you very much!  I greatly appreciate it!  That did the trick!

Comment: I must have missed those with all of the actual sheets that had REF literally written on them.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hint: always search for `#` if something is strange ;)